# Render bibliography using `pandoc-citeproc` in HTML

Tags: html, pandoc, citations

Is it possible to use `pandoc` (or `pandoc-citeproc` directly) to render a bibliography and references in an HTML document?

For a minimal example, assume I have some sort of bibliography:

@article{SomePerson2014, ...}

And an HTML file with Pandoc-style citations:

```
...
As mentioned in @SomePerson2014,
...
```

I want this to render to the following HTML code:

```
... As mentioned in <span class="citation">Person (2014)</span>, ...
<div class="references">
<p>Person, Some. 2014. “The Merits of Existence.” <em>The People’s Journal</em>.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I resorted to exploiting Pandoc markdown's embedded HTML, basically rending an HTML fragment, embedded in "markdown", to HTML using the `pandoc-citeproc` filter.

It works, though the generated HTML isn't perfect (a lot of invalid `<p>` tags are inserted).